# A problem with table with three columns

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a problem with table. What packages does this code need? I am using overleaf and I am not familiar with LaTeX. 
Really looking forward to your help!!!
Thanks~

```
\begin{spacing}{1.1}

\begin{longtable}{p{.1\textwidth}p{.7\textwidth}m{.3\textwidth}}
\caption{description}
\label{table1}
    \toprule   
    \multicolumn{1}{m{1.5cm}}{\centering Symbol} & \multicolumn{1}{m{6cm}}{\centering Definition} & \multicolumn{1}{m{2cm}}{ Unit} \\
    \midrule   
     $V$ & index & -- \\
     $X$ & The  & -- \\
     $Y$ & The & -- \\
     $Z$ & The  & -- \\
    \bottomrule  
\end{longtable}
\end{spacing}
\end{center}
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
update
why[image] my new code will make my subsection and table in two different pages?

```
\subsection{Notations}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{lXl}
\caption{description}
\label{table1}\\
    \toprule   
     Symbol &  Definition & Unit \\
    \midrule   
     $V$ & index & -- \\
     $X$ & The  & -- \\
     $Y$ & The & -- \\
     $Z$ & The  & -- \\
    \bottomrule  
\end{xltabular}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One problem per question please! In following answer deal only with table issues.

In your code fragment you use `longtable`. It is intended for tables longer than one page. Does your table is such? Lets consider that this is the case ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, label font=bf]{caption}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{longtable}{p{\dimexpr0.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
                  p{\dimexpr0.65\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
                  p{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\caption{description}
\label{table1}                  \\  
    \toprule
    \thead{Symbol} & \thead{Definition} & \thead{Unit} \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Description (cont.)} \\
    \toprule
    \thead{Symbol} & \thead{Definition} & \thead{Unit} \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
% multi page table body    
$V$ & index & -- \\
$X$ & The   & -- \\
$Y$ & The   & -- \\
$Z$ & The   & -- \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

In above MWE (Minimal Working Example) I limited to table only. In it

- is defined table caption on the first and all others pages, note on all table foots except last one, that table is continued on the next page
- in column width calculation is considered space between table contents and column border, consequently table width is equal to text width
- for column headers are used command `thead` from the `makecell` package

This MWE gives:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

In the case, that table can be fit in one page, than you instead of `longtable` can use ordinary `tabular` or `tabularx`. Please, provide more information about your table!

Answer (score 1):

To simply make your code compilable, you will need the following 4 packages: `longtable`, `setspace`, `array` and `booktabs`. You will also have to add an `\\` right after the `\label` command. In the following example, I have also removed the `center` environment since longtables are automatically centered given they fit into the textwidth. You can also replace the `\multicolumn{1}{m...}{\centering ...}` commands with `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}`.

Your table unfortunately does not fulfill this premise since 0.1 + 0.7 + 0.3 adds up to more than 1 and the small horizontal white spaces between table columns are not taken into account. I have visualized this using the `showframe`  package. The red lines you see in the following screenshot show the textwidth and the margins.

[image]

I therefore suggest a slightly different approach based in the `xltabular` package that can automatically adapt to the textwidth (or an othr given length). This approach is also shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable} % used only for first table: longtable environment
\usepackage{setspace}  % used only for first table: spacing environment
\usepackage{array}     % used only for first table: m column type

\usepackage{booktabs}  % used for boh tables: \toprule, \midrule \bottomrule

\usepackage{xltabular} % usd only for second table: xltabular environment


%%%%%%%%%% used to visualize the textwidth and borders with red lines. 
%%%%%%%%%% Do not use in actual document! 
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
%\begin{center} %<-------- removed since longtables are automatically centered
\begin{spacing}{1.1}

\begin{longtable}{p{.1\textwidth}p{.7\textwidth}m{.3\textwidth}}
\caption{description}
\label{table1}\\  %<-------- addad a \\ here
    \toprule   
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Symbol} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Definition} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Unit} \\
    \midrule   
     $V$ & index & -- \\
     $X$ & The  & -- \\
     $Y$ & The & -- \\
     $Z$ & The  & -- \\
    \bottomrule  
\end{longtable}
\end{spacing}
%\end{center}


\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{lXl}
\caption{description}
\label{table1}\\
    \toprule   
     Symbol &  Definition & Unit \\
    \midrule   
     $V$ & index & -- \\
     $X$ & The  & -- \\
     $Y$ & The & -- \\
     $Z$ & The  & -- \\
    \bottomrule  
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool! But I meet another problem when I use your code. I hope to add this table after  a subsection, but now this table is in another new page, and it's really confused me. My new codes will be added in question.

Comment: @龙泽伟, the reason may be the width of the table. It is wider than text width.

Comment: @Zrako, could you help me refresh the code? my code has updated in my question.

Comment: @龙泽伟 - There are more efficient ways to keep sectioning headers together. A starting point would be the `placeins` package and its `\FloatBarrier` directive. Just search this site for the words `placeins` and `\FloatBarrier`, and you'll find lots of postings. In general, if a table and its sectioning header aren't placed on the same page, a leading reason is that there simply isn't enough space to place both on the same page.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Thanks for the hint. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @龙泽伟: With the information currently given in your question, the behaviour is not reproducible. If I take my MWE and add a `\section` and `\subsection` command before the `xltabular` and a `\section` command after the `xltabular` I get the following output withou the unexpected page break: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvB9h.png

Comment: @龙泽伟: Could you therefore please try to prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). This is a small document starting with the documentclass you use and all the relevant packages. You can create such a document by copying your current not working document. Then you comment out parts of the code, recompile and see if the error persists. If so, continue untill you have such a small document that still produces the undesired pagebreak. Then include this document into your question.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @Mico: Is `placeins` and `\FloatBarrier` really relevant here? I always though `longtable` and `xltabular` wouldn't float.

Comment: @leandriis - You raise a valid point. My impression (which could well be incorrect!) was that the OP could benefit from some generic advice, so that's why I volunteered the `placeins` information. The OP's specific situation is sufficiently hazy as to allow any definitive diagnosis.